# How to run Mocha tests from PhpStorm without forcing the --ui parameter

Tags: intellij-idea, mocha.js, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm trying to figure out how to run `mocha` tests from PhpStorm (should be the same for WebStorm as well) in environment where I need to use custom `--ui`.

PhpStorm forces me to select one of the predefined "User interface" options in the "Run/Debug Configurations" window. In my situation I'm loading options from a [custom `.opts` file](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/support/debug.opts) that defines the `--ui` that I need.

[image]

However my `--ui` is then overridden by the one defined by PhpStorm:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /my/project/rxjs/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha
    --opts spec/support/default.opts
    --ui tdd
    --reporter /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/plugins/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js
    /my/project/rxjs/spec-js/operators/bufferCount-spec.js
```

I can of course setup just `node` template and set all `mocha` as a script to execute with all its parameters but it'd be more comfortable to use the predefined Mocha options in PhpStorm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to override the UI specified in configuration with the one from `.opts`. But you are not limited to the list of predefined UIs suggested in dropdown: the `User interface` field is editable, so you can enter your UI name there instead of choosing the UI from dropdown

Comment: Ahaaa, I didn't know I can write whatever I want there :).

Comment: This is also relevant for intellij